# Append -1 to all but delete null

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I was wondering how I can append -1 to a column in my database that has a valid entry, but if that column is null i'd like to delete it.

```
           update [dbo].[tbl_company] set [company_id] = concat([company_id], '-1');
```

How would i add the delete record if tbl_company is null?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot delete rows in an update statement. Create 2 separate statements instead.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle same can be achieved using `procedure` .

Comment: Yes of course. I'm only informing the OP that is is not possible using 1 statement, **as that is the initial question**.

Answer (score 4):

```
 DELETE FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id IS NULL;
 UPDATE tbl_company SET company_id = concat(company_id, '-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_Delete()
BEGIN

update [dbo].[tbl_company] set [company_id] = concat([company_id], '-1') where company_id is not null;

DELETE FROM [dbo].[tbl_company] set [company_id] WHERE company_id is null;


END;
```

You can create procedure and just call that procedure.
However you have multiple table's update and delete query there,it can also be achieved using this procedure.

Try above code.

Hope this will help you.